# Poisson Process

Tags: statistics

Assume emails arrive in your inbox modeled by a Poisson process with a mean of 4 per hour.  Let $X$ denote the the time unitl your next e-mail, which is therefore exponentially distributed.

Find the mean Time until the next email you receive

Find the Mean Number of emails you expect to get in the next 5 minutes.

I'm having trouble after reading through my lecture slides and Khan Academy :\

Comment: Poisson processes are generally denoted by $\{N_t\}_{t\geq 0}$, and for each $t \geq 0$, $N_t$ is an integer. What does this integer represent in the context of your question? What is the "inter-arrival" time in the context of your question? Also consider the following great resource: http://www.randomservices.org/random/poisson/index.html

Answer (score 2):

- The number of emails you receive is Poisson distributed.
- The time until the next email you receive is exponentially distributed.
- The mean of a Poisson distribution is $\lambda$.
- The mean of an exponential distribution is $\lambda^{-1}$.
- $\lambda$ is the intensity of the Poisson process.

I think that is enough information to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

The "arrival rate" $\lambda = 4$,

The arrival time of the next email is exponentially distributed, so the mean is $\frac{1}{\lambda} = 1/4$, which is 15 minutes.

In poisson process, the probability of k emails in $\tau$ time is

$p(k, \tau) = e^{-\lambda \tau} \frac{(\lambda \tau)^k}{k!}$

here, $\lambda=4$ and $\tau = 1/12$, so $\lambda \tau = 1/3$

so the expection of poisson distribution is $\lambda^{'} = 1/3$, here $P_{poisson}(k) = e^{-\lambda^{'}} \frac{{\lambda^{'}}^k}{k!}$